# How do you properly extend PHP classes that use other extended classes without strict warnings

Tags: php, inheritance

Imagine i have 2 classes (i've simplified the logic here):

```
class Table {
    public function addRow (Row $row){
        $this->row = $row;
    }
    // lots of code
}
class Row {
    // lots of code
}
```

And i want to extend the table class to do something similar so i create 2 new classes:

```
class SpecialTable extends Table{
    public function addRow (SpecialRow $row){
        parent::addRow($row);
    }
    // lots of code
}
class SpecialRow extends Row{
    // lots of code
}
```

When i try to add a SpecialRow to a SpecialTable object i get a warning similar to:

```
PHP Strict standards:  Declaration of SpecialTable::addRow() should be compatible with that of Table::addRow() in /SpecialTable.php on line XX
```

Can someone help me here? Is this bad practice and i should code it differently? Or is it just a warning that i should ignore?

Many thanks for any suggestions / guidance.

Comment: I don't see you extending. you know... extend "class SpecialRow extends Row"

Comment: oops... you are right. edited to add the extends.

Comment: I seriously think you need to put the real classes in... there's more to this picture than the simple code can paint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use a name like SpecialTable::addSpecialRow() if you're changing the argument type - otherwise SpecialTable doesn't actually **extend** Table, it **overloads** it (which isn't supported in PHP).

Based on your simplified example, it should be `public function addRow(Row $row)` since you just call the parent.  Depending on what you're actually doing to $row in that function, you could type-hint `Row` and check whether it's a `SpecialRow` in code, or just use Row if you don't need its `Special`ness.

Comment: Ok. So overloading the method is not supported. Shame, but at least i know what's going on now. I like the idea of type-hinting to check tho'

Answer (score 1):

Make sure SpecialRow extends from Row:

```
class SpecialRow extends Row {
    // lots of code
}
```

And that SpecialTable extends from Table:

```
class SpecialTable extends Table {
    // lots of code
}
```

Comment: sorry - forgot to write that in the code. edited it so it is there now.

Comment: This won't avoid the strict error - a Row which isn't a SpecialRow can't (well, shouldn't) be used in SpecialTable::addRow().

Answer (score 1):

If `Row` and `SpecialRow` aren't directly related (where `SpecialRow` is a specialized `Row` and therefore should `extend Row`), you could use an [interface](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php). PHP doesn't support method overloading without some crazy ugliness, so an alternative might be something like this:

**Interface**:

```
interface IRow
{
        // interface body
}
```

**Row classes**:

```
class Row implements IRow
{
}

class SpecialRow implements IRow
{
}
```

**Table classes**:

```
class Table
{
        public function addRow(IRow $row)
        {
                $this->row = $row;
        }
}

class SpecialTable
{
        public function addRow(IRow $row)
        {
                $this->row = $row;
        }
}
```

**Implementation**:

```
$t = new Table();
$st = new SpecialTable();

$r = new Row();
$sr = new SpecialRow();

$t->addRow($r);
$st->addRow($sr);
```

http://ideone.com/TsVw5

Comment: interesting... i've not used interfaces before (noobish). Just to make sure: if the SpecialRow uses much of the same code as Row (it just has some extra ways to store the data) should i be using an interface? Would i then end up duplication a lot of my code?

Answer (score 0):

Since it doesn't follow PHP's standards I'd call it bad practice. The point is that a derivative class should always work like its ancestor. So classes expecting a Row argument can handle a SpecialRow the same way. You're extending the class, not overloading it. I'd suggest adding another method for this purpose.